# Is it necessary to create new app for homepage models in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to add a slider to my homepage. What is best way to do it? Should I create a new app for slider? Or can I create a class for slider in home(app)/models.py?

I tried to create Slider class in home/models.py. But I couldn't list on homepage.

home/views.py

```py
def slider_index(request):
    slides = Slider.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'slides': slides})


def slider_detail(request, id):
    slide = get_object_or_404(Slider, id=id)
    context = {
        'slide': slide,
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

home/models.py

```py
class Slider(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, verbose_name='Başlık')
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='Açıklama')
    publishing_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Yayınlanma Tarihi', auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('slide:detail', kwargs={'id': self.id})
        # return "/slider/{}".format(self.id)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-publishing_date', '-id']
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_view),
    path('slider/', slider_index, name='index'),
    path('slider/<int:id>/', slider_detail, name='detail'),
    path('post/', include('post.urls')),

]
```

and home.html:

```py
{% for slide in slides %}
            <!-- Slide #1 image -->
                {% if slide.image %}
            <img src="{{ slide.image.url }}" alt="{{ slide.content }}" title="{{ slide.title }}" />
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Nothing appears about slider. I'm newbie in django. I want to learn how to list slides in homepage.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked whether there is anything in `slides = Slider.objects.all()`

Comment: @MatthewGaiser thank you. I forgot that I deleted all slides when I moved it to home app.